# JavaScript FileReader hangs on 10mb+ files

Tags: javascript, html, windows, filereader

Have simple html page opened in local browser, reads a file selected on form. Works fine, except on any file >10mb it hangs for minutes before loaded event triggers. This happens on Windows 11 x64, 32gb memory, all major browsers. Works on Macbook, both Macos and Windows 11 ARM running on parallels. Any clues what could be causing this?

```
        <input type="file" id="inputFile">
```

...

```
        let file = document.getElementById("inputFile").files[0]

        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file);

        reader.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
            const data = e.target.result;
            console.log(data.length)
        })
```

Comment: What do you see in Chrome's Performance tab? FWIW, this code runs _instantly_ (including the final `console.log` line) in Chrome 116 on Windows when reading a 20MB plaintext file on my HD.

Comment: less than two seconds to load a 100MB file (I'm on a 199 euros entry-level laptop): https://jsfiddle.net/3Lypzswx/

Comment: Just some advice in posting questions here: FileReader has been a stable of JavaScript for quite a while; if what you are experiencing was generally true, don't you think there'd be lots of information about this problem already on the internet, as well as ways around it? And if that information doesn't exist, might you think that "oh, maybe the problem is just me". I don't mean to be rude or to put you down, I just want to encourage you in situations like this to think a little harder / text your problem a little harder before posting here.

Comment: @ControlAltDel - the post clearly states - it's one machine issue. You are adding no value to this.

Comment: @Val Okay, so what troubleshooting steps have you taken on this _one-machine_ of yours? We're still waiting for you to post the results of Chrome's Performance profiler - Safari has one too. Until then, we can't really help you (though I speculate that Parallels is messing with your VM's IO somehow, and Windows 11's Windows Defender can also really mess with IO perf in non-bare-metal environments. What happens if you disable all unnecessary services in the VM? Is there anything in Parallel's logs about performance issues? Are you trying to read a file that's actually on iCloud/OneDrive?

Comment: @Val Just to confirm, you're saying it's _slow_ on Chrome 116 running on Windows 11 x64 inside a Parallels VM on an Apple Silicon machine _and_ it's slow in Chrome 116 on Windows 11 ARM (also in Parallels)? But it's _fast_ in Safari on bare-metal macOS? What about Chrome in bare-metal macOS?

Comment: @Dai - it's idle time. Nothing is happening. Eg out of 10s in profiling 25ms spent on JS, the rest is idle. This is a corporate machine and the only idea I have is firewall / data protection software blocking or throttling this. Eventually, load completes after few minutes. But it's not stuck on slow loading, simply no bytes coming thru if file >10mb, then they start coming after a long time.

Comment: So it isn't actually "hanging" or blocking any threads and the browser isn't actually frozen? It's just slow at reading the file? (If so, then you should retitle your question, because "hang" implies the user-facing application process is entirely unresponsive to user-input (i.e. the UI thread is blocked - or deadlocked).

Comment: I don't think it's "slow". It doesn't do anything but waits, I suspect from OS, to start receiving bytes. All browsers on this machine have this problem. Edge, Chrome, Firefox. I tried to run this on another machine which is macbook - works flawlessly. Not just on macos but virtualized windows as well. Correct, browser is NOT frozen

Comment: Use `wpr` (and `wpa`, `logman`, etc) to record an ETW trace of all IO operations in your Windows 11 machines, that will help you suss it out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/built-in-recording-profiles

Comment: It ended up being DLP (Sophos) that blocked the request. It didn't block it entirely, which made difficult to spot

Answer (score 0):

Sophos DLP is what caused this issue.

What complicates troubleshooting is that eventually, files get loaded, so no obvious errors.

Nothing can done about this as it is desired behavior from corporate security perspective.